Not removing braces around items in a clist or sequence
According to interface3, braces are removed from items in a clist or sequence:

if the item is surrounded by braces, one set is removed, and the result
is passed to the mapped function.

Is there a way to keep these braces around the items? I haven't tested this, but I assume that this could be done using \str_replace_all:Nnn, but certainly isn't an elegant solution.
I was hoping that using \seq_set_split:Nnn would fix the problem, and it almost does in that it produces a list that contains the braces I want:

{1+x}
{1}
{{1}}.

Unfortunately, as the MWE below shows, they braces don't persist when I try to use them, which is weird.
Here's a MWE that shows that the outer braces around each of the items are removed using both clists and sequences. I would like the braces to still be intact when the items reach \__pi_test:n.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\Test {m}
{
    Initial~list:~\tl_to_str:n {#1} \\

    % clist test - fails
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \__pi_test:nn {clist} {##1} }

    % seq_from_clist test - fails
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \__pi_test:nn {seq} {##1}}

    % seq_set_split test - fail too
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {,} {#1}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \__pi_test:nn {split~seq} {##1}}
    \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
}

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__pi_test:nn #1 #2
{   % #2 should still be braced, if it started off that way
    #1:~\tl_to_str:n {#2}.\\
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \Test{ {1+x}, {1}, {{1}} }

\end{document}


why don't you simply brace the items as you use them?

If the braces were not stripped there would be no way of having an item with a comma that did not have a brace as part of the data

@DavidCarlisle The input that I want to work with could be something like 123,{123}. In my code, the first item is parsed correctly and further split into the sequence (1,2,3), whereas the second item should be parsed into the sequence (123).  Unfortunately, because the braces disappear,  I am unable to differentiate between 123 and {123}. I also can't brace the items  before passing them to the next macro because in my actual code I am using \peek_charcode:NTF to parse the items in the list. Perhaps I need to peek for the commas too.

well of course anything is changeable but the official line that the correct input syntax for a clist of two items 123 and {123}  is 123,{{123}}   that is you need to do something special to get a { in an item value, just as you need to do something special to get a , into a value.

I guess my code only fails in the case where there is a single braced multi-token item in my list. For example, 123,{123}4 is parsed correctly. Perhaps I can live with that. Thanks!

yes exactly, an outer brace group surrounding the item is the syntax used to esape commas, any other braces are left in place

Removing outer braces from a macro parameter is TeX feature. And LaTeX uses TeX. This feature (removing braces) has nothing to do with expl3 macros.

@wipet actually it does, as that's the documented behaviour of expl3, and if the documented behaviour was different it would've been implemented differently. For instance it also strips the braces in  {abc} , (note the spaces around {abc}).

@Skillmon Expl3 only documents the TeX feature about removing outer braces. You cannot implement keeping outer braces of parameters separated by comma by TeX macros without catcode dancing or similar obscure solution. Removing outer braces is not expl3 feature, this is TeX feature. It may be an unwelcome feature, but it's there.

@wipet it actually is. expl3 uses something akin to \grabNext\empty#1, and then strips the \empty by expanding it once using \expandafter. Afterwards it strips surrounding spaces (without accidentally stripping surrounding braces), and only then it strips one set of surrounding braces.

In any case the expl3 source code can be found in  source3, the code that removes the braces can be found by searching for "Unless we are done with the loop it
calls __clist_wrap_item:w to unbrace the item" --- you can modify it as needed, possibly use the \prg_do_nothing: trick (as seen in the implementation of \__clist_trim_next:w) to avoid removing the braces
